# Drag and drop templates edit, text images and save

Tags: jquery, python, content-management-system

I have seen many drag and drop applications.. how to build similar to that? What are technologies used in that?

ex: https://www.webydo.com/
ex: contentbuilder.js

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

How about that small drag and drop example to see more as you can see there is this guy doing nice drag and drop tables [See this guy Example drag and Drop on table for Mini](http://www.redips.net/javascript/drag-and-drop-table-content/)
and now see my fiddle this build table something like drag and move that section it will build it at background and you can download later hope this will help little bit i tried to help thank you
[fiddle Table](http://jsfiddle.net/Munkhdelger/jAj62/79/)

i post this for help nothing else

```
 data-content="
                      <form class='form'>
                        <div class='form-group col-md-12'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Label Text</label> <input class='form-control' type='text' name='label' id='label'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Placeholder</label> <input type='text' name='placeholder' id='placeholder' class='form-control'>
                          <label class='control-label'>Help Text</label> <input type='text' name='help' id='help' class='form-control'>
                          <hr/>
                          <button class='btn btn-info'>Save</button><button class='btn btn-danger'>Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                      </form>" data-html="true">
```